# Maintaining correct aspect ratio while displaying multiple images together

Tags: matlab

I am expecting the following output,

[image]

But, getting the following output

[image]

I.e. the displayed images' have incorrect aspect ratio.

What is the reason and How can I fix this?

---

*Source Code*

**main.m**

```
clear_all();       
image_name = 'woman.png';
I = gray_imread(image_name);
K = {I, I, I, I, ... 
     I, I, I, I, ...
     I, I, I, I};
draw_cell(K);
```

**draw_cell.m**

```
function draw_cell(image_list)   
    if(iscell(image_list))
        figure;
        hold all
        colormap(gray(256));

        N = length(image_list);
        [m, n] = factor_out(N);

        display('cell');
        for k=1:N
            h = subplot(m,n,k);
            image(image_list{k},'parent',h);
            set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
        end
        hold off
    else
        error('''image_list'' is not a cell array');
    end   


function [m, n] = factor_out(input_number)
    sqrtt = ceil(sqrt(input_number));    
    m = sqrtt;
    n = sqrtt;
```

Comment: to the down-voter: may I ask why is my question down-voted?

Comment: Try `imshow` instead of `image`.

Comment: My guess is the down vote is because your code has a few typos and does not run as is. But I'm not sure. Seems well written otherwise.

Comment: @Cecilia, `gray_imread()` and `clear_all()` should be intuitive.

Comment: I agree. I was not the down voter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible options for maintaining aspect ratio of images

1. `axis equal` or `axis image`

For most plotting functions, you can use the `axis equal` command to set the same scale on the x and y axes. While plotting images, this is equivalent to maintaining the aspect ratio. You need to call this command for every subplot, so I would suggest using it immediately after the `subplot` command.

For plotting images specifically, the `axis equal` command will leave white space around the image. `axis image` will maintain aspect ratio and remove white space.

2. `imshow` instead of `image`

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can substitute the `imshow` function for the `image` function. `imshow` makes the assumption that you want to display an image and restricts both the colormap and the aspect ratios accordingly. Despite its name `image` is designed to visualize any matrix data, not just images. Therefore, it scales pixels to fully utilize screen real estate. You'll run into the same problem if you use `imagesc` along with the additional problem of color scaling. To be on the safe side, always use `imshow` when displaying RGB and grayscale images unless you have an explicit reason not to.